# this.objectProperty is undefined inside object literal

Tags: javascript, oop, object-literal

I've been working with object literals for a while now but I'm stumped as to why the object property is returning `undefined` when accessing it using `this` here's an example of what I am trying to do...

```
var x = (function(){
    return{
        a: "1",
        b : this.a
    };
})();

console.log(x.b);
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` is determined by *how the currently executing function was called*.

In this case, it will probably be `window` (if you are running in a browser and not in strict mode)

There is no way to refer to an object, constructed using an object literal, while it is being constructed.

You have to do it in two steps.

```
var x = (function(){
    var obj = {
        a: "1",
    };
    obj.b = obj.a;
    return obj;
})();

console.log(x.b);
```

Comment: ah ok I get it. that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to return the object, which will assign the invoking object to `this`

```
var x = (function(){
    return{
        a: "1",
        b : function(){return this.a;}
    };
})();
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AFtT5/1/

You could also use a [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) method:

```
var x = (function(){
    return{
        a: "1",
        get b (){return this.a;}
    };
})();

console.log(x.b);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AFtT5/2/

Comment: I'm using this.propertyName elsewhere and it's working, in fact I've got the file open and it's right there... do I really need to return it in a function?

Comment: sorry, were I'm using it is within a function

Comment: without the function `this` refers to the global object, which in the case of FF is `window`, within the context of a function `this` will refer to the object invoking the function.  If you have further questions let me know, hope this helps.